# sql insere o datetime errado na tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

eu to usando microsoft sql manager,e estava tentando inserir uma data na minha tabela,o problema é que ele está inserindo a data errada,eu faço o seguinte comando para a tabela do manager

```
INSERT
INTO tblCliente /*minha tabela que eu criei*/
VALUES('Ze',1999-10-02,1) /*atributos da tabela:nome[nvarchar[50]],data[datatime],limiteCliente[decimal(18,2)]*/
```

porém ao clicar para rodar o codigo da tabela,acontece isso
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém que possua experiência em sql poderia me dizer como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Faltam aspas na data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que aconteceu é que o valor 1999-10-02 foi considerado como uma expressão numérica:
     1999 - 10 - 2 = 1987
E esse valor numérico foi acrescentado ao menor valor de data disponível para datetime, que é 1/1/1900. Algo semelhante a:

```
-- código #3
SELECT dateadd(day, 1999-10-02, 0)
```

Como a segunda coluna está declarada como *datetime*, recomendo que informe o valor entre apóstrofos. Por exemplo:

```
-- código #1
INSERT into tblCliente
   VALUES('Ze', '19991002', 1);
```

Dessa forma, sem hífens.

Pode também utilizar a função Convert, caso queira informar a data em outro formato. Por exemplo, para informar a data no formato dd/mm/aaaa:

```
-- código #2
INSERT into tblCliente
   VALUES('Ze', convert(datetime, '2/10/1999', 103), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma

INSERT INTO tblClientes VALUES ('Zé', '1999-10-02', 1)

A data tem que ser inserido como string.